# Linking dynamically created/populated divs to their respect database row in table

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm working on a page of a site that will dynamically add a new div (basically a contact card) based on information it pulls from a database. So, for each new row added to the database, a new div (contact card) will added to the page. I'm am strictly using divs, and not a table or list.

With each div (contact card), there is a button I've created called "contact me". When the contact me button is clicked, a modal form appears and allows the user to enter information which I would like to be sent to the owner of that contact card, with (tutor_tutid) being unique identifier of each contact. The information being used to populate the fields of the div(contact card) is pulled from a table called "tutors" and each row has "tutor_tutid" as the primary key.

My problem is, I don't know how to tell HTML that, for example, when the "contact me" button of DIV1 (contact card1) is clicked, the form that the user should fill out at the next step should automatically be assigned to "tutor_tutid: 1" from the "tutors" table. And, DIV1(contact card1) "contact me" button to "tutor_tutid: 2" and so on.

I know how to write the code to insert the information filled in into the desired table. I just don't know how to link each div/contact me button to user whose information it's displaying. I think I might need jQuery to do this, but I don't know how.

Here's what I have:

```
<div class="teacher-info-container">
  <div id="tic1" class="teacher-info-column">
    <div class="teacher-pic-box">
      <div class="teacher-pic">
        <img src="images/defaulticon.png"></img>
      </div>

      <div class="teacher-name-box">
        Name: '. $row['tutor_tutfirst'] . '
        <br> Native: '. $row['tutor_tutlanguage'] .'
        <br> City: '. $row['tutor_tutcity'] .'
        <br>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="tic2" class="teacher-info-column">
    <div class="tic-column2-header">
      Background, Education and Interests
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="teacher-background-box">

      <div class="tic-column2-fields">
        <div class="tic2-field-one">School
        </div>
        <div class="tic2-field-two">:
        </div>
        <div class="tic2-field-three">' . $row['tutor_tutschool'] . '
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="clear"></div>

      <div class="tic-column2-fields">
        <div class="tic2-field-one">Major
        </div>
        <div class="tic2-field-two">:
        </div>
        <div class="tic2-field-three">'.$row['tutor_tutmajor'] .'
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="clear"></div>

      <div class="tic-column2-fields">
        <div class="tic2-field-one">Experience
        </div>
        <div class="tic2-field-two">:
        </div>
        <div class="tic2-field-three">' . $row['tutor_tutexp'] .' years
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="clear"></div>

      <div class="tic-column2-fields">
        <div class="tic2-field-one">Skill
        </div>
        <div class="tic2-field-two">:
        </div>
        <div class="tic2-field-three">'. $row['tutor_tutskill1'] . ', ' . $row['tutor_tutskill2'] . ', '. $row['tutor_tutskill3'] .'
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="clear"></div>

      <div class="tic-column2-fields">
        <div class="tic2-field-one">Teaches
        </div>
        <div class="tic2-field-two">:
        </div>
        <div class="tic2-field-three">' . $row['tutor_tutlessonmode1'] . ', '. $row['tutor_tutlessonmode2']. '
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="clear"></div>

      <div class="tic-column2-fields">
        <div class="tic2-field-one">Hobbies
        </div>
        <div class="tic2-field-two">:
        </div>
        <div class="tic2-field-three">' .$row['tutor_tuthobby1'] . ', ' . $row['tutor_tuthobby2'] . ', ' . $row['tutor_tuthobby3'] . '
        </div>
        <div class="hide-id">'.$row['tutor_tutid'].'</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="tic3" class="teacher-info-column">
    <div class="introduction-box">
      <div class="introduction-header">Introduction</div>
      <div class="introduction-body">' . $row['tutor_tutintro']. '</div>
      <button id="fatmodalButton" class="tic3-button">CONTACT ME
                    </button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You can do it with jQuery, but since you are *not very experienced* I would suggest you might want to load the form with something like an iframe in the modal. The contact me button can be a link to a new page with a query param which contains the tutid.

Comment: I'm keeping my clothes on

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You may have an XSS vulnerability in your database outputs - you need to ensure that any HTML is escaped or removed before echoing it to the page.